# CXF WS-Security on Mule 3 embedded in JBoss

Tags: cxf, x509certificate, ws-security, mule

I have a CXF web service that I would to secure with a x509 certificate. One approach I tried was to wrap it on a servlet endpoint with mule 3.x.

```
<servlet:inbound-endpoint path="localhost:8080/myapp/mule/services/authrequest">
        <cxf:jaxws-service
            serviceClass="myapp.webservices.v1_01_40.AuthPortType"
            validationEnabled="false">
        </cxf:jaxws-service>
        <custom-security-filter class="myapp.InitialSecurity"></custom-security-filter>
    </servlet:inbound-endpoint>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mule/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
    <param-value>xml config files</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I am trying to wrap it on a servlet to try to use my custom login module (JAAS) on jBoss. I am not sure if this is the best approach. I really need to have a ws-endpoint secured by a x509 certificate on jBoss. I have this scenario working using a Mule 1.x and jBoss 4.2.3 and a custom JAAS login module. I need to migrate this app to mule 3.x and jBoss 6.1. I saw some examples online that told me I had to change the message header and add something else, but I can't do that. The message has to stay the same.

When I deploy this on jboss 6.1 I get this error:

```
ERROR [org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet] message: Endpoint "authrequest" not found: org.mule.api.transport.NoReceiverForEndpointException: Endpoint "authrequest" not found
```

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Kelly

Comment: Never heard about Mule3. Why not to use [CXF+WS-Security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html#WS-Security-UsingX.509Certificates)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Servlet inbound endpoint path is not a full URI but the relative path of your resource.

Try:

```
<servlet:inbound-endpoint path="authrequest">
```